# Oracle database not opening files with '#' character in them

Tags: oracle, url, plsql, oracle-apex

For some reason, the files in the database won't open if they have the # character in them...

One thing i noticed was in the file name, the link doesn't have %20 for the space characters after the # sign, but even when i replace the rest of the number characters with the %20 character, the link still doesn't work..

Any ideas why it could be?

---

Added from comments
I looked more into the code and it seems like this is what actually opens the files; wpg_docload.download_file(v_filename, false);

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to open these files?  UTL_FILE.FOPEN()?  Or something else?

Comment: i'm not really sure, just by using link schema_name/docs/file_name

Comment: actually i looked more into the code and it seems like this is what actually opens the files;

wpg_docload.download_file(v_filename, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wpg_docload.download_file is part of Apex and is used to return files to a browser.
But # can have a special meaning in a URL so that might be confusing it.

Have a look in WWV_FLOW_FILES and see what the file name is in there (eg has it been encoded in anyway).

Comment: it's stored in a 'renamed' table called Documents i think but the name is not encoded... the Name column has a string like 'F1087964252/Filename' the beginning part changes... But yeah there is no encoding...

How can I encode the file names and still be able to allow users to download the file with the original file name (including the #)?

Comment: I guess i'm not going to get any more answers for this question. I will accept yours, at least now i know i need to encode the url somehow, but i have no idea where to start...